# jQuery, how to set inputs are required notifications for more than one input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have 3 inputs, two of which are required, so I want to add a class (invalid) for each required input and show the label text below that this field is required if it is empty or empty by user (on change )

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"  class="requiredfiled">

<div class="error_required s-help-block cart_hidden">
    <label style="color: #fb6100;">Name is required</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  class="requiredfiled"> 

<div class="error_required s-help-block hidden">
    <label style="color: #fb6100;">Phone is required</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address"  class="">
```

I tried this code but not worked with me

```
$(".requiredfiled").change(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).hasClass("requiredfiled")) {
            $(this).addClass("invalid");
            $(".error_required").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
            $(".error_required").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this logic:

- No need to loop through all required text fields as you're already inside one text field during change `event`.
- No need to use `$(this).hasClass('requiredfiled')` as you are already running the event handler on that selector. So, the input already has that class otherwise event won't have fired.
- You can use `keyup` event for better effect & validation.
- You can just transverse the next `error_required` after current text field using `$(this).next('.error_required')`
- You can use [`.toggleClass(className, state)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) syntax to minimise the code.

**DEMO HERE:**

```js
$('.requiredfiled').keyup(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('invalid', $(this).val() == "");
  $(this).next('.error_required').toggleClass('hidden', $(this).val() != "");
});

$('#updateaddress').click(function() {
  
  // Check if all required fields have some valid text
  var isFilled = $('.requiredfiled').filter(function () { 
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0 
  }).length === 0;
  
  if(isFilled){
    alert('Address was saved successfully!')
  } else {
    // Show the validation error in UI to inform the users
    $('.requiredfiled').each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('invalid', $(this).val() == "");
      $(this).next('.error_required').toggleClass('hidden', $(this).val() != "");
    });
  
    alert('Please enter the required fields!')
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
.invalid {border: 2px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="requiredfiled" placeholder="Name"/>
<div class="error_required s-help-block hidden">
  <label style="color: #fb6100;">Name is required</label>
</div>
<br>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="requiredfiled" placeholder="Phone"/>
<div class="error_required s-help-block hidden">
  <label style="color: #fb6100;">Phone is required</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="" placeholder="Address" />
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="updateaddress">Update</button>
```

Comment: @palaSH how to check also when click other button to save the form and to ensure those required inputs are not empty

Comment: You can check if the length `$('.requiredfiled').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
}).length;` is 0 or not. If 0 it means all required inputs are filled, none are empty.

Comment: can you explain more please? how to excute this function when click saveform button?
$('#updateaddress').click(function() { //if required fields are empty!!!

Comment: I have updated the demo with the click logic. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `$('.error_required')` to `$(this).next('.error_required')` so we can select the correct `.error_required` after the input field.

**Working demo**

```js
$('.requiredfiled').change(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == "") && ($(this).hasClass('requiredfiled'))) {
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
      $(this).next('.error_required').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('invalid');
      $(this).next('.error_required').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="requiredfiled">
<div class="error_required s-help-block cart_hidden ">
  <label style="color: #fb6100;">Name is required</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="requiredfiled">
<div class="error_required s-help-block">
  <label style="color: #fb6100;">Phone is required</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html code

```
  <div class="error_required s-help-block name_error">
    <label style="color: #fb6100;">Name is required</label>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="requiredfiled"> 

  <div class="error_required s-help-block phone_error">
    <label style="color: #fb6100;">Phone is required</label>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="address" id="address"  class="">
```

Here is the Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".requiredfiled").on("input", function(){
        if ($("#name").val().length > 0) {
            $(".name_error").css("visibility", "hidden");   
        } else if ($("#name").val().length == 0) {
            $(".name_error").css("visibility", "visible");  
            $("#name").addClass("invalid"); 
        }

        if ($("#phone").val().length > 0) {
            $(".phone_error").css("visibility", "hidden");      
        } else if ($("#phone").val().length == 0) {
            $(".phone_error").css("visibility", "visible");  
            $("#phone").addClass("invalid");    
        }
    });
});
```

CSS for invalid input field

```
.invalid {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

What we are doing here is detecting the input change using `$(".requiredfiled").on("input", function()` then we detect the length of the input field and based on that we can perform any action. Here i have changed the visibility of the error message. When the input field will be empty the error message will appear.